Removing a phrase (case insensitive) from a sentence in java
I have a java question.  What are some of the ways in java that I could remove just the phrase “Unidentified Issue:” from the string below?  The search for the phrase to be removed should be case-insensitive.
“EUB Error - Recs: Unidentified Issue: Service connection is denied.”
So, basically:
Input string is:  “EUB Error - Recs: Unidentified Issue: Service connection is denied.”
Output string should should be: “EUB Error - Recs: Service connection is denied.”
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
thank you so much in advance!

One good tool that java has is replaceAll() method with a regular expression to remove the phrase "Unidentified Issue:".
public class StackOverflowHelp{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "EUB Error - Recs: Unidentified Issue: Service connection is denied.";
        String output = input.replaceAll("(?i)Unidentified Issue:", "");
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}

(?i) -> makes the regular expression case-insensitive.
replaceAll() -> finds every instance of your first parameter and then linearly replaces all occurrences of the given regular expression with an empty string.
linearly just means from index 0 -> end
This code should output:
EUB Error - Recs:  Service connection is denied.

So, the phrase "Unidentified Issue:" should be removed from the input string.
